# Monad Transformer 'distribute' Function

Tags: haskell

Given the following [Typeclassopedia](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia#Definition_and_laws) exercise:

```
--Implement join :: M (N (M (N a))) -> M (N a), 
--given distrib :: N (M a) -> M (N a) and 
--assuming M and N are instances of Monad.

distrib :: (Monad m, Monad n) => n (m a) => m (n a)
distrib = undefined
```

I get the following compile-time error.

```
ghci> :l MonadTransformers.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( MonadTransformers.hs, interpreted )

MonadTransformers.hs:7:34:
    Expected a constraint, but `n (m a)' has kind `*'
    In the type signature for `distrib':
      distrib :: (Monad m, Monad n) => n (m a) => m (n a)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should be

```
distrib :: (Monad m, Monad n) => n (m a) -> m (n a)
```

`=>` comes between the constraint and the rest of the type.

`->` is the infix type constructor for functions.

For example

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
       -----     \  /      \
        \         arguments result
         constraint
```

Comment: I blame ~~Scala~~ (myself) for the `=>`. Thanks

Comment: Kevin Meredith: Yeah, I imagine it doesn't help that in Scala, constraints are (implicit) arguments.

Comment: Are constraints resolved as implicits in Haskell too?

Comment: sort of. type classes constraints are transformed by the compiler into dictionary arguments. which dictionary is used at call time is determined by type inference.