# Implementing `distrib` Function

Tags: haskell, monads

After getting [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640717/monad-transformer-distribute-function/29640792#29640792) on an error where I used `=>` rather than `->`, I'm trying to implement `distrib`:

```
distrib :: (Monad m, Monad n) => n (m a) -> m (n a)
distrib x = do xx <- x
               return xx
```

But, this does not work given the compile-time error:

```
Expected type: m (m a)
  Actual type: n (m a)
```

I realized that using `do` notation won't work since, when calling `xx <- x`, the expected return type (of the `do` block) is `x`, i.e. `n (m a)` - that's not what I want.

Please give me a hint on how to implement this function.

Comment: The type given has no implementation.  For example, `IO (Maybe a) -> Maybe (IO a)` would allow us to find out some information about what an `IO` action returned without running it. You need to assume more about `m` and `n`.  [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040844/applicatives-compose-monads-dont) might be an interesting thread.

Comment: Er wait I meant [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29453915/composing-monads-v-applicative-functors/29454112#29454112)

Comment: See [Concrete example showing that monads are not closed under composition (with proof)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13034229/1333025).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This function can't be written for two arbitrary monads, but it does exist when the outer type is [Traversable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:sequence), as some (but not all) Monad instances are:

```
sequence :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => t (m a) -> m (t a)
```

You could then define

```
distrib :: (Monad m, Traversable m, Monad n) => m (n a) -> n (m a)
distrib = sequence
```

but this doesn't buy you anything, so you might as well just use `sequence` when appropriate.